# HTML header and footer tag issue in IE

Tags: html, header, footer

In my HTML I used `<header>` and `<footer>` tags, but when I check it in IE it doesn't render—the layout is breaking. Is that because of the HTML version? I tried removing those tags and then my layout didn't break.

Here is my code:

```
<header id="main-header"> 
<div class="navigation-wrapper">
<hgroup id="logo">
    <a href="/"><h1><span class="hide">Heading</span></h1></a>
</hgroup>
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1"> 
    <ul class="dropdown"> 
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Profile</a>
        </li> 
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="navotar.com/"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Log out</a>
        </li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: i am referring to "header" and "footer" tags

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic

Comment: No that is not because of HTML version it is because IE is a very bad browser...

Comment: http://modernizr.com/  GO and read

Comment: Sorry, this is the markup
----------------------------
<header id="main-header">
  <div class="navigation-wrapper">
    <hgroup id="logo"><a href="/"><h1><span class="hide">Heading</span></h1></a></hgroup>
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://navotar.com/"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

Comment: could you not have put that in your question instead of commenting it @iSK ?

Comment: @anushman, Thanks i agree, but what you suggest, do i have to remove those tags and do it as usual way?

Comment: @anushman, i did put, but its dropped

Comment: The latest IE displays those elements just fine. So, what version do you need to support?

Comment: Finally i did an experiment on this, Solved the problem, We can use this script to avoid html5 issues on old browsers.

<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of IE can't style elements they do not recognize, so they won't render elements that were introduced after the browser was published.

Fortunately there's a way around it:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement('header'); document.createElement('footer');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can also use HTML5shiv or modernizr which do this for the whole set of HTML5 elements.